# Passing functor object by reference doesn't work in std::generate_n()

Tags: c++, stl

I made a `FibonacciSeries` functor for using in `std::generate_n()`, but it doesn't work the way it should be. Passing the functor by reference doesn't work well.

In the following program, `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13` is the expected output, but I get `0 1 1 2 0 1 1 2` as the output. What could be wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

inline void printvec(const vector<int>& vec)
{
    for (const auto& v : vec)
        cout << v << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}


class FibonacciSeries
{
private:
    int f1;
    int f2;
    int f3;
public:
    FibonacciSeries() :f1(0), f2(1) {}
    int operator() () {    
        f3 = f1 + f2;
        int  result = f1;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
        return result;
    }
    void printstat(){
        cout << f1 << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    FibonacciSeries series;
    //passing function object by reference
    generate_n<back_insert_iterator<vector<int>>, 
        int, FibonacciSeries&>(back_inserter(vec), 4, series);

    printvec(vec);// prints 0 1 1 2

    series.printstat();//prints 0//unexpected
    
    //passing function object by value
    generate_n(back_inserter(vec), 4, series);
    printvec(vec);//prints 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 2//unexpected
}
```

Comment: A debugger might help!

Comment: Try `std::ref(series)` instead of just `series`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: what compiler are you using ? I couldnt reproduce with gcc trunk

Comment: Why do you believe you need to pass the object by reference? What problem do you believe it will solve?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OP wants to retain the state of the functor between two calls to `generate_n`

Comment: Were you still using `FibonacciSeries&` as the explicit template argument, or did you change that to `std::reference_wrapper<FibonacciSeries>`, or better, just let the compiler deduce all template arguments?

Comment: @mmj -- Given what you are claiming, [cannot duplicate the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/Yefq3e3vh).

Comment: There are many simpler ways, @463035818_is_not_a_number, of accomplishing the same thing. In both cases, the generator can be a simple lambda that captures the state by reference. Problem solved.

Comment: It works on gcc. I checked it now. But it doesn't work on Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @mmj *But it doesn't work on Visual Studio 2013* -- FYI -- Visual C++ 2013 lacked some C++11 features.  The first compiler that Microsoft has as being C++11 compliant was VS 2015.  And to be honest, if you are not using, at the very least, Visual C++ 2015 with update 3, expect other surprises when "good" C++11 code does strange things.

Answer (score 3):

I wasnt able to reproduce the issue with gcc trunk (https://godbolt.org/z/PfPPE67h8). However, standard algorithms may copy functors passed to them internally. Not sure what is actually going "wrong" in the implementation but suppose the algorithm starts with

```
  std::remove_reference<Generator> g = generator;
```

And uses that to generate the output. One would have to read the implementation to see whats causing your output. However, using `FibonacciSeries&` as explicit template argument is the wrong approach. Even if the generator is passed by reference it may be copied internally.

The simplest to avoid such issues as you are observing now, is to not rely on functors with state. Rather than making the state member of the functor, let it capture state by reference and store the state elsewhere. Either use a lamba, as suggested by Sam in a comment, or write your custom wrapper:

```
struct FibonacciSeriesWrapper {
    FibonacciSeries& parent;
    int operator() () { return parent(); }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    FibonacciSeries series;    
    //passing function object by reference
    generate_n(back_inserter(vec), 4, FibonacciSeriesWrapper{series});
    generate_n(back_inserter(vec), 4, FibonacciSeriesWrapper{series});
    printvec(vec);//prints 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bzTqqn7Yc)

Comment: You can just use `std::ref(series)` instead of defining the wrapper type.

Comment: @aschepler that did not work

Comment: @mmj why did it not work? Looks fine here https://godbolt.org/z/es8GsbMs1

Answer (score 1):

Your generator (`FibonnachiSeries` object)  is copied to `std::generate_n` call. So original object state is not changed. One workaround may be passsing a lambda

```
generate_n(back_inserter(vec), 4, 
           [&series] { return series(); });
```

// UPD: nevermind, declaring `FibonacchiSeries` as a reference should have helped. Your version works fine for me. What compiler do you use?

Comment: the argument of `generate_n<back_insert_iterator<vector<int>>, int, FibonacciSeries&>` is `FibonaccieSeries&`

Comment: ...as you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/fxhYoh87h gcc prodces expected output. This wouldnt be the case if the functor would be passed by value

Comment: year, you're right. My bad. Edited.

Comment: I use visual studio 2013

Comment: looks like some compiler bug. Does version with lambda work for you?

Comment: Yes version with lambda worked.